# Node.js mongoose advance Search get query from user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to set raw query from node to mongodb with mongoose driver.
I got the query from user using javascript

```
var keys = $('#advance-search').val();
```

then I Post the keys to the node server and trying to using the query in find() like the following:

```
var search = req.query.keys || ""
Product.find(keys)...
```

the problem is the type of `keys` is String and `find()` need object

when I tried to convert `keys` to object by `keys = JSON.parse(keys)` I got exception because the mongo query not a valid Json format
example: `{'product.price' :{ $in :[500,400,300,600]}}`

so what is the best way to make a raw query from html to mongo by node js, and how I can filter this query before execution?

Comment: What does `keys` variable look like exactly ? And what's your schema ? please

Comment: my keys is `{'product.price' :{ $in :[500,400,300,600]}}`, i just trying to execute a raw query from html

Comment: `{'product.price' :{ '$in' :[500,400,300,600]}}` Put quotes on the `$in` as shown. The JSON parse exception is because an uinquoted key is invalid JSON. When it's parsed however, it's a perfectly valid JavaScript Object.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, double quote work, thank you